# VBA User form with ThemeColorScheme and late binding

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to run a user form with status bar.

I show my form with code bolow.
How should I declare variables and assigning new values to those variables?

Very important: **I have to use late binding in my project**.

```
Sub RunMyUserForm()

With MyUserForm
    .LabelProgress.Width = 0
    .TextBox1 = 1
    'to make the progress bar color match the workbook's current theme:
    .LabelProgress.BackColor = ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent1)
    .Show vbModeless
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Updated information:

1. When I try to run my macro with "Option Explicit", it doesn't work (`Compile error: Variable not defined` - part of code `msoThemeAccent1` is marked as yellow color). That's why I asked for help in defining the variables.
2. When I try to run my macro without "Option Explicit", it dosen't work (`Err.Description: "Value is out of range"`, `Err.Number: -2147024809`)
3. When I try to run my macro with early binding (reference to "MS Office Object Library" via Tools/References in VBE) everything works perfect with (and without) "Option Explicit".

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You declare variables the same way you always do, with a `Dim` statement (or `ReDim`).  Working between forms, modules, etc., you may need to make more use of passing arguments, or variables with a global/public scope, but the fundamentals of instantiating a variable, and assigning it a value, do not change.  Let me know if you need more clarification, or please provide more detail about what you're asking :)

Comment: David, more details:

1. When I try to run my macro with "Option Explicit", it doesn't work ("Compile error: Variable not defined" - part of code ("msoThemeAccent1") is marked as yellow color). That's why I asked for help in defining the variables.
2. When I try to run my macro without "Option Explicit", it dosen't work (Err.Description: "Value is out of range", "Err.Number: -2147024809")
3. When I try to run my macro with early binding (reference to "MS Office Object Library" via Tools/References in VBE) everything works perfect with (and without) "Option Explicit".

Comment: I think I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is seeing `msoThemeAccent1` as a variable, and it is undeclared. This is why your code won't run with `Option Explicit` and also why your code raises an error when you disable `Option Explicit`.  `.Colors` is a 1-based collection (?) so when you call:

`ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent1)`

It is compiling to:

`ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(0)`

Which raises an expected, albeit cryptic error.

I used some code to check the value of this constant, but in hindsight I should have just referred to the documentation:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080559557.aspx

**This should fix it for you**

`ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(5)`

Alternatively, if you need to rely on this value in several places in your code, you could declare a variable (public or private, scope depends on what you need it for).

`Public Const myAccentColor1 as Long = 5`

And then, in your code you could:

`ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(myAccentColor1)`

**Revised**

I understand now, without reference to MS Office Object Library this makes sense.  This is one of the few libraries that I maintain a reference to in my XLSB file, so my confusion was a result of the fact that I thought I was using an appropriate late-binding, but I was really using early-binding.

Comment: David, thank you very much for all your help and useful information! After reading your answer I changed `ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent1)` to `ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(5)` and my macro works correctly now :-) Many thanks for your help!